# Mobile: Open multiple new tabs from anchors (__blank)

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I've got a mobile web app that has multiple anchors with `target='__blank'`.  When the first anchor is clicked, the browser will open up a new tab and load the desired page.  When subsequent anchors are clicked, the desired page is loaded in the same new tab.

The desired effect is to have each anchor open up a new tab when clicked, so that multiple tabs can be opened at the same time.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `_blank`. Just a single underscore. Your double underscores are creating a window actually named `__blank`, causing all links to target that particular window.